# Google Map Marker is showing inside water?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not understanding why my Google Map Marker is inside water. It will show the correct location when I Zoom out the Map. Any Idea?

[image]

Comment: @Tomas, Thanks, I have shrink the market icon image to 9*9. The map now very much improved.

Comment: I don't understand your comment...

Comment: I am using a marker icon image(see red circle above). Previously it's size was 22*18(app). I have scale this image to 9*9. Now the marker is not showing inside water. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only idea that comes to me, is that your coordinate(latitude and longitude) is not exact. Are you sure you have the format :

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
```

latitude should be first and longitude second.

Try locating the exact latitude, longitude using below:

[Find Latitude and Longitude](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html)

Comment: Yes, I have this. Lat Lang is not a problem because when I zoom out the map, it points the correct location.